# console.log("string") is not printing outside two for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log, nested-for-loop

```js
for (var i = 4; i <= 4; --i) {
  var str = "";
  for (var j = 4; j <= 4; --j) {
    str = str + " " + j;
  }
  console.log(str);
}

//why below line is not printing in console?[enter image description here][1]
console.log("another Pattern");

for (var k = 4; k >= 1; ++k) {
  var str = "";
  for (var l = 4; l <= 1; ++l) {
    str = str + "" + k;
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Your first loop never stops running (both `i` and `j` will _always_ be <= 4.)

Comment: Your For-Loops aren't terminating and therefore infinite. The For-Loop starts at 4 and checks if the value is less or equal to 4 and continues and after that, it reduces the value by 1 to 3 and so on. It keeps going as it will never be higher than 4.

Comment: should be i and j >= 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two infinite loops above. The counting variables i and j always meet the condition equal or less 4. The console output line below the comment is never reached.